# Why does this comma inside a ternary operator throw a syntax error in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, syntax-error, language-lawyer, ternary-operator

I noticed something odd when trying to use the comma operator inside the conditional (ternary) operator for logging. Here's a contrived example:

```js
const a = 2;
const b = 1;
a > b ? console.log(a), a : b; //I expect this to log and evaluate to a
```

But instead I'm met with this:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,
```

According to the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), the conditional operator accepts two expressions as the 'if' and 'else' cases of the ternary operator, and the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) theoretically *is an expression* as,

> The comma operator evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand.

So why do I get a syntax error? The comma operator is an expression which should be allowed to be in a conditional operator. Although, putting parentheses around the comma's operands works fine:

```
a > b ? (console.log(a), a) : b; //Logs and gives a
```

Why does that work fine? Parentheses (or the [grouping operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping)) allows the interpreter to *know* it's dealing with an expression, but `console.log(a), a` is *already* an expression without the need of parentheses, so why do I get a syntax error without them?

Comment: I've made a couple of edits but am *not* removing the `ecmascript-6` tag event though I think the only reason it's even applicable is that you needlessly use the `const` keyword instead of just `var`

Comment: @GeorgeJempty I was going for just ECMAScript (without a version) since I use the specification in the answer but it doesn't exist, though that's a good point. I'd say it's fine with the your edit, thanks.

Comment: Glad you're ok with adding "ternary operator" to the title, I think it will make it more google-able.  All in all great self-answered Q&A, I've done a few of these myself and they've never gotten this reception.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is an intentional part of the language, and is outlined in the [ECMAScript Language Specification](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/). The syntax for the comma operator is defined in [Section 12.16](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-comma-operator), which states the following:

> ### 12.16 Comma Operator ( , )
>
> #### Syntax
>
> ```
> Expression:
>   AssignmentExpression
>   Expression, AssignmentExpression
> ```

Here, the specification outlines how the comma operator is used. An *`Expression`* is any *`AssignmentExpression`* or itself followed with a comma (the operator) and another *`AssignmentExpression`*. The important thing to note is that an *`AssignmentExpression`* is an *`Expression`* but an *`Expression`* is **not** an *`AssignmentExpression`*.

As for the actual conditional operator, the grammar for the operator and conditional expressions is specificed in [Section 12.14](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-conditional-operator):

> ### 12.14 Conditional Operator ( ? : )
>
> #### Syntax
>
> ```
> ConditionalExpression:  
>   LogicalORExpression  
>   LogicalORExpression ? AssignmentExpression : AssignmentExpression
> ```

By the specification, a conditional expression can only contain *`AssignmentExpression`* s -- not just *`Expression`* s. Thus a conditional operator cannot have a comma operator inside one of its operands. This may seem like a weird quirk of language, but there is a specific reason considering the very specific grammar, and per the specification:

> NOTE   
>   The grammar for a *`ConditionalExpression`* in ECMAScript is slightly different from that in C and [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-ConditionalExpression), which each allow the second subexpression to be an [*`Expression`*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-Expression)<sup>1</sup> but restrict the third expression to be a [*`ConditionalExpression`*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-ConditionalExpression). **The motivation for this difference in ECMAScript is to allow an assignment expression to be governed by either arm of a conditional** and **to eliminate the confusing and fairly useless case of a comma expression as the centre expression.**

Because of Java and C's restrictive grammar, they do not allow things like this (Java):

```
int a = 2;
int b = 1;
System.out.println(a > b ? b = a : a = b); //Can't use assignment in 'else' part
//                                 ^^^^^
```

ECMAScript authors decided to allow for assignment in both branches of the ternary operator, thus this definition with *`AssignmentExpression`* occurred. Consequently, this definition also disallows for the comma operator to actually show up in the 'if' part of the conditional operator, but because of its scarcity and uselessness it wasn't a problem. They essentially killed two birds with one stone; allowed for more lenient grammar and got rid of useless syntax that's bad practice.

The reason why adding the grouping operator allows it to work is because the grouping operator production *`( Expression )`* is by definition also an *`AssignmentExpression`* allowing it to be in the ternary operator, see [str's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48043910/5647260) for more details.

---

<sup>1</sup> This refers to *Java's `Expression`*, not ECMAScript's *`Expression`*. Java's does **not** have the comma operator so its  *`Expression`* does not include it.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is meant as an extension of [Li357's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48039188/906113). Specifically to show where in the grammar the Conditional Operator allows `PrimaryExpression`s (which does not include the Comma Operator) but not `Expression`s (which does include the Comma Operator).

---

*Please see the links to the specification for every mentioned type of expression or operator on the bottom of this answer.*

The specification of the Conditional Operator is defined as follows:

> ```
> ConditionalExpression:
>   LogicalORExpression
>   LogicalORExpression ? AssignmentExpression : AssignmentExpression
> ```

Thus it can be either a `LogicalORExpression` only, or a combination of `LogicalORExpression` and two `AssignmentExpression`s. An `AssignmentExpression` itself can, among other things, be specified by a `LogicalORExpression` as well.

But unlike its simple sounding name, the `LogicalORExpression` is not just a basic condition but can consist of many, many different nested expressions itself.
All the way down to `PrimaryExpression` which also includes grouped expressions `(Expression)`.

And as can be seen in the specification of the Comma Operator, it is only specified in `Expression`, but not in `PrimaryExpression` itself.

> ```
> Expression:
>   AssignmentExpression
>   Expression , AssignmentExpression
> ```

To summarize it in simpler words: The grammar of JavaScript only allows the comma operator within an `AssignmentExpression` if it is contained within a grouping operator `()`.

Also see the [Operator Precedence in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).

## Resources

- [Conditional Operator `?:` and `ConditionalExpression`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-conditional-operator)

  - [`AssignmentExpression`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-assignment-operators)
  - [`LogicalORExpression`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#prod-LogicalORExpression)

    - ...

      - [`PrimaryExpression`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#prod-PrimaryExpression)

        - [`CoverParenthesizedExpressionAndArrowParameterList`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#prod-PrimaryExpression)

          - [Comma Operator `,`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-comma-operator)

Comment: I was going to include this in mine but I felt it was too much that would just elongate the answer without much value. But as an extension this works nice. +1

Comment: "*somewhat related is the Operator Precedence*" - no, it's not "somewhat related", this whole question is all about operator precedence! :-D

Comment: @Bergi The precedence is not specifically documented in the specification (at least I did not find anything) but implicitly given by the grammar. That and the fact that MDN is not the authoritative source for JavaScript is why I phrased it like that. But you are right of course, I changed that sentence.